# jQuery matching multiple classes

Tags: jquery

For the first time, I got in this kind of unusual situtation

I have to select a div on which more than 2 classes are applied, that to in random order

For Example:

Assume that I have a <div> on which following 3 classes are applied
content-text, right-align and bold-font. I need to select this div, but problem is that classes are applied in different order on different pages

```
<div class="content-text right-align bold-font">...</div>
<div class="right-align content-text bold-font">...</div>
<div class="content-text bold-font right-align ">...</div>
...
```

How can I select this particular div, no matter how classes are applied?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will work fine. CSS selectors in general don't care about the order of classes, just the ones that are applied. This also goes for jQuery:

```
$('div.content-text.right-align.bold-font');
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for me until I add spaces before classes 2-n: `$('div.content-text .right-align .bold-font');`

Comment: @SweatCoder You're targeting an element with the class `bold-font` that is nested under an element with the class `right-align` that is nested under a `div` element with the class `content-text`. This is a different arrangement of classes/elements than is being asked about in this question.