# Selecting particular class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how i would go about selecting this class and changing it to a span12 once the screen size is below 1000px using jquery

```
<div class="span4 minus65">
```

I am using

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).outerWidth() < 1000){
        $('.span4 minus65').attr('class',"span12");
    }

});
```

but nothing changes when the screen width is below 1000px

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery matching multiple classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732122/jquery-matching-multiple-classes)

Comment: So you want us to solve your problem [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545845/change-the-name-of-a-div-jquery-or-css) at a time? This question has been asked countless times, all you need to do is _search_, and _try_.

Comment: yeah sorry, trying to get a better understanding, i shouldnt have asked last question as the ids where irrelevant, but by seeing a successful solution it helps me understand what is happening so that next time i can do it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use media queries, you should use "addClass" and "removeClass"

```
$(el).addClass('span12').removeClass('span4');
```

Depending on the browser, "resize" sometimes will fire, and sometimes will fire too often. You should take the function you're using in the "resize" event and fire it periodically like so:

```
var resizeFunc = function(){
    //add/remove classes
};

//"fix" the sizing even if "resize" doesn't fire.
setInterval(resizeFunc(), 1000);

jQuery(document).resize(resizeFunc);
```

Also, resize will fire...A LOT. You can also "throttle" it so that it doesn't fire more than once every few hundred milliseconds.

You should probably consider using media queries for this (which has good support in newer versions of IE and all the other modern browsers:

http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries

Comment: im using jquery for better support in older IE browsers :(

Comment: That's fine, addClass/removeClass will do what you need. You should still consider throttling the func, or just firing it every few hundred ms.

Comment: any tips on how to go about that?

Comment: thanks for the info, wasnt aware resize can fire sporadically dependent on browser

Comment: I would highly recommend you use something like Underscore.js for this, technically, debounce might actually do a better job for you, but underscore supports either (and loads of other great stuff): http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Answer (score 2):

for select div with multiple class

```
$('.span4.minus65')
```

and for replace all classes:

```
$('.span4.minus65').removeClass().addClass('span12');
```

or replace only one class

```
$('.span4.minus65').removeClass('span4').addClass('span12');
```

Comment: it MUST works :) I've tested it. (see edit) If don't, the error is somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use the [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) funcitons

e.g.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).outerWidth() < 1000){
        $('.span4 minus65').removeClass('span4').addClass('span12');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, that makes total sense,remove and then add which when i think about it is literally what i am doing..thank you